# git, как сделать changelist или что-то похожее

Tags: git, git-commit, repository, commit

Есть проект с git. Я внес изменения, но я не хочу что бы они комитились и потом заливались в origin, т.е. надо что бы они были только у меня локально. Как сделать так что бы git их или не видел, или еще что-то с ними сделать что бы они не попадали в commit. А все остальные изменения попадали.

Comment: не хотите, что бы файлы коммитились - не добавляйте их в индекс (git add) и не используйте git commit  с параметром -a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данного действия существует `.gitignore`. [Документация](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Вы просто создаете отдельный файл `.gitignore` где лежит `.git` репозиторий, куда помещаете перечисления файлов, папок, которые не должны быть залиты при commit/push. Изменения так же не будут видны при `git status` и в интерфейсе IDE.

Что же касается игнориования отдельных строк, то здесь немного сложнее и не так удобно, но в [документации здесь](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%90%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-Git), прочитайте параграф "Разворачивание ключевых слов".

По типу файла можно определить фильтры в `.gitattributes` файле, которые будут применяться при изменениях.